# How to replace a variable inside a string in bash

Tags: bash

I have a string env variable which looks like below

```
data={\"data\":{\"sources\":\"some value\", \"destination\":\"some other value\"}}
```

I would like to include date (say YEAR) within this env variable. That is, I have another env variable called `YEAR` (bash: YEAR=2019) and I would like to use this variable (YEAR) inside `data`. Here is what I need to do

```
data={\"data\":{\"sources\":\"some value ${YEAR}\", \"destination\":\"some other value\"}}
```

but it does not work, how can I make it work?

Comment: What's the error? Can you show your actual code?

Comment: single quotes don't evaluate anything inside even with a $ sign

Answer (score 0):

Use `jq`:

```
$ echo "$data" | jq --argjson y "$YEAR" '.data.sources += " \($y)"'
{
  "data": {
    "sources": "some value 2019",
    "destination": "some other value"
  }
}
```

or

```
# Note the -c argument to compress the data to a single line
$ data=$(echo "$data" | jq -c --argjson y "$YEAR" '.data.sources += " \($y)"')
$ echo "$data"
{"data":{"sources":"some value 2019","destination":"some other value"}}
```

Comment: please assume it's not json, it was just an example. besides, due to some limitations I can't install jq

Answer (score 0):

Alternative, using here documents, minimizing the need to escape quotes, while still supporting variable substitutions:

```
data=$(cat <<DATA
   "data": {
       "sources":"some value ${YEAR}",
       "destination":"some other value"
    }
}
DATA
)
```